# What is the recommended way to use a Paterson Super System 4 tank?

Tags: developing

Every single thing I've read about the Paterson tanks suggests that you can use the rotary agitator instead of inversion. One would think that the manufacturer's own published materials would provide the answers.

The website for the
[Super System 4 Developing Tanks](https://www.patersonphotographic.com/product/paterson-super-system-4-developing-tanks/) states:

> Agitation of the processing solutions can be by inversion of the tank
> using the flexible water tight cap provided, or by rotary agitation
> using the agitation rod also provided.

Whereas  The [PDF](https://www.patersonphotographic.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/GREYSCALE-FinalSupertanksFULL.pdf) states,

> After pouring in the first solution, insert the agitator and twist
> sharply back and forth three or four times [...] Now push the cap on
> [...] At the end of the first minute and of each subsequent minute,
> invert the tank.

So, what it is,  is the rotary agitator  an alternative to inversion, or it is  to be used once at the start and not thereafter?

Comment: Personally I found inversion was often leaky, so I used agitation only.

Answer (score 1):

Either is ok.

Agitation should be done according to the instructions for the *developer* (and other chemicals) because different developers vary in chemical process and so do films and the photographer’s intent.

The Paterson instructions are a place to start. When the lid is on properly, the tank won’t leak when inverted and inversion is usually an acceptable method of agitation irrespective of developer used, the film stock, and photographer’s intent.

But because developing film is often an art, a good analogy for a Paterson tank is a kitchen appliance: the instructions for a slow cooker describe how to plug it in, turn it on, and the importance of using the lid, but a recipe will have more detail and might include additional steps such as overnight marinading in the crock prior to cooking, occasional stirring, or even cooking without the lid.

Learning to develop your own film means you will make mistakes and learn from them. Some of the mistakes will be big and the roll will be lost. Some will be small and you will try to do it better next time. The only way to learn is to do it and mess up sometimes.